# Convert Record to Serialized Form Data for sending via HTTP

Tags: jquery, delphi, serialization, delphi-2010

Is there a way to convert this Record

```
TError = record
  code: Word;
  message: String;
end;

TState = record
  caption: String;
  address: Cardinal;
  counters: TArray<Word>;
  errors: TArray<TError>;
end;
```

to serialized Form Data string (`Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`) like

```
caption=Foo&
address=175896&
counters[]=2&
counters[]=2&
errors[0][code]=52&
errors[0][message]=ERR_NOT_AVAILABLE
```

for sending via HTTP?

Maybe there is some function similar to [JQuery.param()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/)?

Comment: may this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984362/delphi-win32-serialization-libraries

Comment: @hardik thanks, but I already read it. I need something a little differ from a usual serialization to xml or json.

Comment: You can do your own serialization format if that's what you are asking. If you asking how to do that, study delphi implementations of json and xml plus how to use rtti. See [Convert any record to a string and back?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10956790/576719) for an example. Or Robert Love's [XMLSerial](http://code.google.com/p/robstechcorner/source/browse/trunk/Delphi/rtti/xmlserial.pas)

Comment: @LURD, I can write my own serialization, but before I start to do this I think that It already exists, because somebody had already asked same question.

Comment: You might mention that you want a Delphi function similar to [JQuery API .serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/). Perhaps add the `jquery`tag will help. Or follow this link [Custom-JSON-serialization-of-any-dynamic-array-content](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2012/04/12/Custom-JSON-serialization-of-any-dynamic-array-content) and ask [Arnaud Bouchez](http://stackoverflow.com/users/458259/arnaud-bouchez) in their forum if there exists a solution.

Comment: @LURD, thanks. I'll try. I think It should be more similar to [JQuery.params()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) than to [JQuery .serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, here is a boilerplate solution which can be adapted for your specific serialization or other use as well.

A record, `TSerializer`, does all the serialization job and the result is stored in a string list.

To use it, call method `Serialize('state', TValue.From(state),sList);` from a `TSerializer` instance.

You can add most types that fit into a `TValue`, including records, static arrays, dynamic arrays and simple classes. The unwinding of all elements are made by recursion.
(Disclaimer, this is tested on XE2, but I think Delphi-2010 supports all enhanced-RTTI calls used here)

The output from your example looks like this:

```
record state:TState
  caption:string=Foo
  address:Cardinal=175896
  dynamic array counters:Word
    counters[0]:Word=2
    counters[1]:Word=2
  end
  dynamic array errors:TError
    record errors[0]:TError
      code:Word=52
      message:string=ERR_NOT_AVAILABLE
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the source unit:

```
unit SerializerBoilerplate;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, Classes, RTTI, TypInfo;

Type
  TSerializer = record
  private
    FSumIndent: string;
    procedure IncIndent;
    procedure DecIndent;
  public
    procedure Serialize(const name: string; thing: TValue;
      sList: TStrings; first: boolean = true);
  end;

implementation

procedure TSerializer.IncIndent;
begin
  FSumIndent := FSumIndent + '  ';
end;

procedure TSerializer.DecIndent;
begin
  SetLength(FSumIndent, Length(FSumIndent) - 2);
end;

procedure TSerializer.Serialize(const name: string; thing: TValue;
  sList: TStrings; first: boolean);
type
  PPByte = ^PByte;
var
  LContext: TRTTIContext;
  LField: TRTTIField;
  LProperty: TRTTIProperty;
  LRecord: TRTTIRecordType;
  LClass: TRTTIInstanceType;
  LStaticArray: TRTTIArrayType;
  LDynArray: TRTTIDynamicArrayType;
  LDimType: TRttiOrdinalType;
  LArrayIx: array of integer;
  LArrayMinIx: array of integer;
  LArrayMaxIx: array of integer;
  LNewValue: TValue;
  i: integer;
  // Generic N-dimensional array indexing
  procedure IncIx(var ArrayIx, ArrayMinIx, ArrayMaxIx: array of integer);
  var
    dimIx: integer;
  begin
    dimIx := Length(ArrayIx) - 1;
    repeat
      if (ArrayIx[dimIx] < ArrayMaxIx[dimIx]) then
      begin
        Inc(ArrayIx[dimIx]);
        break;
      end
      else
      begin
        ArrayIx[dimIx] := ArrayMinIx[dimIx];
        Dec(dimIx);
        if (dimIx < 0) then
          break;
      end;
    until (true = false);
  end;
  // Convert N-dimensional index to a string
  function IxToString(const ArrayIx: array of integer): string;
  var
    i: integer;
  begin
    Result := '';
    for i := 0 to High(ArrayIx) do
      Result := Result + '[' + IntToStr(ArrayIx[i]) + ']';
  end;
  // Get correct reference
  function GetValue(Addr: Pointer; Typ: TRTTIType): TValue;
  begin
    TValue.Make(Addr, Typ.Handle, Result);
  end;

begin
  if first then
    FSumIndent := '';

  case thing.Kind of
    { - Number calls }
    tkInteger, // Identifies an ordinal type.
    tkInt64, // Identifies the Int64/UInt64 types.
    tkPointer: // Identifies a pointer type.
      begin
        sList.Add(FSumIndent + name + ':' + thing.TypeInfo.name + '=' +
          thing.ToString);
      end;
    tkEnumeration:
      begin
        if (thing.TypeInfo = TypeInfo(boolean)) then
        begin
          sList.Add(FSumIndent + name + ':' + thing.TypeInfo.name + '=' +
            BoolToStr(thing.AsBoolean));
        end
        else begin
          // ToDO : Implement this
        end;
      end; // Identifies an enumeration type.
    tkSet: // Identifies a set type.
      begin
        // ToDO : Implement this
      end;
    { - Float calls }
    tkFloat: // Identifies a floating-point type. (plus Date,Time,DateTime)
      begin
        if (thing.TypeInfo = TypeInfo(TDate)) then
        begin
          sList.Add(FSumIndent + name + ':' + thing.TypeInfo.name + '=' +
            DateToStr(thing.AsExtended));
        end
        else if (thing.TypeInfo = TypeInfo(TTime)) then
        begin
          sList.Add(FSumIndent + name + ':' + thing.TypeInfo.name + '=' +
            TimeToStr(thing.AsExtended));
        end
        else if (thing.TypeInfo = TypeInfo(TDateTime)) then
        begin
          sList.Add(FSumIndent + name + ':' + thing.TypeInfo.name + '=' +
            DateTimeToStr(thing.AsExtended));
        end
        else
        begin
          sList.Add(FSumIndent + name + ':' + thing.TypeInfo.name + '=' +
            FloatToStr(thing.AsExtended));
        end;
        // ToDO : Handle currency
      end;

    { - String,character calls }
    tkChar, // Identifies a single-byte character.
    tkString, // Identifies a short string type.
    tkLString: // Identifies an AnsiString type.
      begin
        sList.Add(FSumIndent + name + ':' + thing.TypeInfo.name + '=' +
          thing.AsString);
      end;
    tkWString: // Identifies a WideString type.
      begin
        sList.Add(FSumIndent + name + ':' + thing.TypeInfo.name + '=' +
          thing.ToString);
      end;
    tkInterface: // Identifies an interface type.
      begin
        // ToDO : Implement this
      end;
    tkWChar, // Identifies a 2-byte (wide) character type.
    tkUString: // Identifies a UnicodeString type.
      begin
        sList.Add(FSumIndent + name + ':' + thing.TypeInfo.name + '=' +
          thing.AsString);
      end;

    tkVariant: // Identifies a Variant type.
      begin
        // ToDO : Implement this
      end;

    { - Generates recursive calls }
    tkArray: // Identifies a static array type.
      begin
        LStaticArray := LContext.GetType(thing.TypeInfo) as TRTTIArrayType;
        SetLength(LArrayIx, LStaticArray.DimensionCount);
        SetLength(LArrayMinIx, LStaticArray.DimensionCount);
        SetLength(LArrayMaxIx, LStaticArray.DimensionCount);
        sList.Add(FSumIndent + 'static array ' + name + ':' +
          LStaticArray.ElementType.name);
        IncIndent();
        for i := 0 to LStaticArray.DimensionCount - 1 do
        begin
          LDimType := LStaticArray.Dimensions[i] as TRttiOrdinalType;
          LArrayMinIx[i] := LDimType.MinValue;
          LArrayMaxIx[i] := LDimType.MaxValue;
          LArrayIx[i] := LDimType.MinValue;
        end;
        for i := 0 to LStaticArray.TotalElementCount - 1 do
        begin
          Serialize(Name + IxToString(LArrayIx),
            GetValue( PByte(thing.GetReferenceToRawData) +
              LStaticArray.ElementType.TypeSize * i,
              LStaticArray.ElementType),
            sList,false);
          IncIx(LArrayIx, LArrayMinIx, LArrayMaxIx);
        end;
        DecIndent();
        sList.Add(FSumIndent + 'end');
      end;
    tkDynArray: // Identifies a dynamic array type.
      begin
        LDynArray := LContext.GetType(thing.TypeInfo) as TRTTIDynamicArrayType;
        sList.Add(FSumIndent + 'dynamic array ' + name + ':' +
          LDynArray.ElementType.name);
        IncIndent();
        for i := 0 to thing.GetArrayLength - 1 do
        begin
          Serialize(Name + '[' + IntToStr(i) + ']',
            GetValue( PPByte(thing.GetReferenceToRawData)^ +
              LDynArray.ElementType.TypeSize * i,
              LDynArray.ElementType),
            sList,false);
        end;
        DecIndent();
        sList.Add(FSumIndent + 'end');
      end;
    tkRecord: // Identifies a record type.
      begin
        sList.Add(FSumIndent + 'record ' + name +':' +thing.TypeInfo.name);
        LRecord := LContext.GetType(thing.TypeInfo).AsRecord;
        IncIndent();
        for LField in LRecord.GetFields do
        begin
          Serialize(LField.name, LField.GetValue(thing.GetReferenceToRawData),
            sList, false);
        end;
        DecIndent();
        sList.Add(FSumIndent + 'end');
      end;
    tkClass: // Identifies a class type.
      begin
        sList.Add(FSumIndent + 'object ' + name + ':' + thing.TypeInfo.name);
        IncIndent();
        LClass := LContext.GetType(thing.TypeInfo).AsInstance;
        for LField in LClass.GetFields do
        begin
          Serialize(LField.name,
            // A hack to get a reference to the object
            // See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802864/rtti-accessing-fields-and-properties-in-complex-data-structures
            GetValue(PPByte(thing.GetReferenceToRawData)^ + LField.Offset,
            LField.FieldType),
            sList,false);
        end;
        // ToDO : Implement a more complete class serializer
        DecIndent();
        sList.Add(FSumIndent + 'end');
      end;

    { - Not implemented }
    tkClassRef: ; // Identifies a metaclass type.
    tkMethod: ; // Identifies a class method type.
    tkProcedure: ; // Identifies a procedural type.
    tkUnknown: ; // Identifies an unknown type that has RTTI.
  end;
end;

end.
```

And a test unit:

```
program SerializerProj;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}

uses
  Classes,
  SysUtils,
  RTTI,
  SerializerBoilerplate;

Type
  TMyObj = Class
  private
    fI: integer;
    fS: string;
  end;

  TInnerRec = record
    A, B, C: string;
  end;

  TDim1 = 1 .. 3;
  TDim2 = 2 .. 5;
  TMyArr = array [TDim1, TDim2] of integer; // Must be typed dimensions

  TTestRec = record
    s: string;
    ws: WideString;
    st: ShortString;
    ansiCh: AnsiChar;
    ansiS: AnsiString;
    wChar: Char;
    B: boolean;
    i: integer;
    t: TTime;
    d: TDate;
    dt: TDateTime;
    fd: Double;
    fS: Single;
    r: TInnerRec;
    arr: TMyArr;
    dArr: array of string;
    o: TMyObj;
  end;

  TError = record
    code: Word;
    message: String;
  end;

  TState = record
    caption: String;
    address: Cardinal;
    counters: TArray<Word>;
    errors: TArray<TError>;
  end;

var
  tr: TTestRec;
  state: TState;
  sList: TStringList;
  s: string;
  Serializer: TSerializer;

begin
  state.caption := 'Foo';
  state.address := 175896;
  SetLength(state.counters,2);
  state.counters[0] := 2;
  state.counters[1] := 2;
  SetLength(state.errors,1);
  state.errors[0].code := 52;
  state.errors[0].message := 'ERR_NOT_AVAILABLE';

  tr := Default (TTestRec);
  sList := TStringList.Create;
  try
    tr.s := 'A';
    tr.ws := 'WS';
    tr.st := '[100]';
    tr.ansiCh := '@';
    tr.ansiS := '@!';
    tr.wChar := 'Ö';
    tr.B := true;
    tr.i := 100;
    tr.t := Now;
    tr.d := Now;
    tr.dt := Now;
    tr.fd := Pi;
    tr.fS := 2 * Pi;
    tr.r.A := 'AA';
    tr.r.B := 'BB';
    tr.r.C := 'CC';
    tr.arr[1, 2] := 12;
    tr.arr[1, 3] := 13;
    tr.arr[1, 4] := 14;
    tr.arr[1, 5] := 15;
    tr.arr[2, 2] := 22;
    tr.arr[2, 3] := 23;
    tr.arr[2, 4] := 24;
    tr.arr[2, 5] := 25;
    tr.arr[3, 2] := 32;
    tr.arr[3, 3] := 33;
    tr.arr[3, 4] := 34;
    tr.arr[3, 5] := 35;
    SetLength(tr.dArr, 3);
    tr.dArr[0] := 'A';
    tr.dArr[1] := 'B';
    tr.dArr[2] := 'C';
    tr.o := TMyObj.Create;
    tr.o.fI := 11;
    tr.o.fS := '22';

    Serializer.Serialize('tr', TValue.From(tr), sList);
    for s in sList do
      WriteLn(s);
    sList.Clear;
    Serializer.Serialize('state', TValue.From(state),sList);
    for s in sList do
      WriteLn(s);

    ReadLn;
  finally
    sList.Free;
  end;

end.
```

I had a little help studying [Barry Kellys answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2810732/576719) to the question [Rtti accessing fields and properties in complex data structures](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2802864/576719).

Comment: Thanks you for detailed answer but I'd already wrote my own serializer using RTTI too and with similar algorithm. I think your example will be useful for others.