# dynamic record access

Tags: delphi, css-selectors, field, records

i'm relativity new to delphi and trying to write a complex search algorithm for my a2 computing coursework. i need to access my record field from a string variable.
e.g.

```
         getfield(record,'name');
```

I have found an article that may solve my problem but i cant make sense of it. please can someone shorten it down to just what i need. Thanks.

http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2010/10/10/fun-with-delphi-rtti-dump-a-trttitype-definition/

Comment: Why don't you try first, and ask a question if you get stuck.

Comment: I have iv'e been trying for days now and i cant make sense of it im really just diving in the deep end here and i need a solution.

Comment: Since the record field is `yours` you probably need not RTTI to access it at all. RTTI is required to get information about the types unknown at compile time.

Comment: @Serg, the field name could be unknown at compile time.

Comment: If you study my answer here, I'm sure you can figure it out: [`Convert Record to Serialized Form Data for sending via HTTP`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11514088/576719).

Comment: http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/03/12/TDynArray-and-Record-compare/load/save-using-fast-RTTI

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A dead simple adaptation of [LU RD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/576719/lu-rd)'s code from [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11514088/576719). This compiles and works under Delphi XE2, but earlier versions should be fine, too.

```
program Project4;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, RTTI, TypInfo;

type
  TSampleRecord = record
    SomeInt: Integer;
    SomeStr: String;
    SomeFloat: Single;
  end;

function GetField(Rec: TValue; const FieldName: String): String;
var
  Context: TRTTIContext;
  RTTIRecord: TRTTIRecordType;
  RecField: TRTTIField;
  RecValue: TValue;
begin
  if (Rec.Kind = tkRecord) then
  begin
    RTTIRecord := Context.GetType(Rec.TypeInfo).AsRecord;
    RecField := RTTIRecord.GetField(FieldName);

    RecValue := RecField.GetValue(Rec.GetReferenceToRawData);
    Result := RecValue.ToString();

    if (RecValue.Kind = tkFloat) then
      Result := Format('%.4f', [RecValue.AsExtended]);
  end;
end;

var
  SR: TSampleRecord;
begin
  SR.SomeInt := 1992;
  SR.SomeStr := 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet';
  SR.SomeFloat := 3.1415;

  Writeln(GetField(TValue.From(SR), 'SomeInt'));
  Writeln(GetField(TValue.From(SR), 'SomeStr'));
  Writeln(GetField(TValue.From(SR), 'SomeFloat'));

  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help. You can easily expand this to support more complex record fields. :) Just have a look at the reference I've used here and you should be able to figure it out in a flash.