# How to determine using Rtti, if a field from a class is a Record

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, rtti

I coded a RttiHelper class, that among other things, can retrieve all field's names of a class. The procedure succesfully determines if a field is an object or an array, but it cannot determine if a field is a Record. Follows code:

```
unit Form1
interface
uses RttiHelper;
type
  tMyRec = Record
   ...
  end;      
...
implementation
var MyRec : tMyRec;
procedure FormCreate (Sender: tObject);
begin
  SetRec (@MyRec);
end;

unit RttiHelper
interface
type
  tObjRec =  class
   Rec    : Pointer;
  end; 
  ...
  tRttiHelperClass = class (tObject)
  private  
    fObjRec: tObjRec;
  ...
    procedure GetFieldsNames;
  ...
  public  
  ...
    procedure SetRec (aRec: Pointer);
  ...
  published
  ...
    constructor Create (aOwner: tComponent);
  ...
  end;
implementation
constructor tRttiHelperClass.Create (aOwner: tComponent);
begin
  fCtxt := tRttiContext.Create;
end;
procedure tRttiHelperClass.SetRec (aRec: Pointer);
begin
  private
    fObjectRec.Rec := aRec;
    procedure GetFieldsNames;
end;
procedure tRttiHelperClass.GetFieldsNames;
var f      :  Word    ;
    fields : tRttiType;
begin
  with fRttiContext do begin
        RttiType := GetType (fObjRec.ClassType);
        Fields   := RttiType.GetFields;
         for f := Low (fields) to High (fields) fo begin
             if fields[f].GetValue (tObject (fObjRec^)).IsArray  then // this works
                ...
             if fields[f].GetValue (tObject (fObjRec^)).IsObject then // this works
                ...
             if fields[f].GetValue (tObject (fObjRec^)).IsRecord then // "undeclared identifier IsRecord"
                ...
  end;
end;
end.
```

I know that in order to work with Records, I must use tRttiRecordType, but I couldn't find the right way to do this. How is the correct code for determining if some field is a Record?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
if fields[f].FieldType.IsRecord then
```

From [System.Rtti.TRttiField.FieldType](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Rtti.TRttiField.FieldType) and [System.Rtti.TRttiType.IsRecord](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Rtti.TRttiType.IsRecord).

---

Now the underlying problem here is you cannot resolve the record fields from an untyped pointer. In order to do something like that, pass your record as a TValue.

```
procedure SetRec( aRec: TValue);
```

Call it this way:

```
SetRec(TValue.From(MyRec));
```

For a more complete tutorial how to do this and resolve the contents of a record, see [Convert Record to Serialized Form Data for sending via HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11514088/576719).

Passing TValue works with classes and other types as well.

Comment: I've tried those, but since fields[f] is infact a pointer, it returns a `tkPointer`. There must be a way to check the Record that is pointed by fields[f].

Comment: Ahh misread the question. There is no RTTI available for records this way. You must pass the type of the record to your helper.