# Data missing while sending data from ClientSocket (Mobile) to ServerSocket (Server)

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, vcl, delphi-10.1-berlin, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I'm using FireMonkey in Delphi 10.1 Berlin for developing an Android mobile client application, and I'm using VCL in Delphi 10.1 Berlin for developing a Windows server application.

In the mobile application, I am using `TIdTCPClient` for sending the following record:

```
PSampleReq = ^TSampleReq ;
TSampleReq = packed record
  Value1: array [0..10] of Char;
  Value2: array [0..59] of Char;
  Value3: array [0..40] of Char;
  Value4: Int64;
  Value5: array [0..9] of Char;
  Value6: array [0..9] of Char;
  Value7: Integer;
end;
```

I have filled the packet with data and am sending the packet using the following code:

```
FIdTCPClient.IOHandler.Write(RawToBytes(TSampleReq,SizeOf(TSampleReq)));
```

While reading the data in the Server application, I am not able to read the `Value5`, `Value6`and `Value7` fields. Below is the code that is reading the data:

```
Move(tyTIDBytes[0], SampleReq, SizeOf(TSampleReq));
```

For receiving the data which is send from the client socket, I have used the TIDTcpServer and handled the below code in Execute method:

```
TServerRecord = packed record
PointerMessage : TIndyBytes;
ClientSocket   : TIdTCPConnection;
end;

Var    
ReceivedIDBytes: TServerRecord;
begin
if not AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
begin
AContext.Connection.IOHandler.InputBuffer.ExtractToBytes(ReceivedIDBytes.PointerMessage.tyTIDBytes) ;
ReceivedIDBytes.ClientSocket := AContext.Connection;
MessageProcessorThread.ProcessMessageQueue.Enqueue(ReceivedIDBytes);
end;
```

After this I'm processing the data from Queue and the processing method I have mentioned below:

```
var
InputRec: TServerRecord;
begin
InputRec := DBWorkerThread.DBWorkerQueue.Dequeue;
MessageHeaderPtr := @InputRec.PointerMessage.tyTIDBytes[0];
iHMMessageCode := StrToIntDef( Trim(MessageHeaderPtr^.MessageCode), UNKNOWN_MESSAGE_CODE);
case iHMMessageCode of
1001:
begin
Move(InputRec.PointerMessage.tyTIDBytes[0], SampleReq, SizeOf(TSampleReq));
end;
end;
```

And in this I'm not able to read the Value5, Value6 and Value7 fields.

With the below Link, I have found some optimized technique and how I can handle the packets properly without any packet missing. Please help me out to resolve this issue.

[Sending the right record size over socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41131478/)

Comment: Did you validate that `sizeof(TSampleReq)` is exactly 276 bytes in *both* apps? You did not show your *actual* reading code that is populating `tyTIDBytes` before you call `Move()` on it. The code should be something like this: `var tyTIDBytes: TIdBytes; ... AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadBytes(tyTIDBytes, SizeOf(TSampleReq), False);` And FYI, Indy has a `BytesToRaw()` function as a companion to `RawToBytes()`: `BytesToRaw(tyTIDBytes, SampleReq, SizeOf(TSampleReq));`

Comment: And FYI, you are not using the "optimized technique" described in that [other link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41131478/). That technique sends the data size before sending the actual data. The Indy equivalent would look something like this: `tyTIDBytes := RawToBytes(SampleReq, SizeOf(TSampleReq); FIdTCPClient.IOHandler.Write(Int32(Length(tyTIDBytes))); FIdTCPClient.IOHandler.Write(tyTIDBytes);` ... `AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadBytes(tyTIDBytes, AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadInt32, False); BytesToRaw(tyTIDBytes, SampleReq, SizeOf(TSampleReq));`

Comment: please [edit] your question to show the *actual* code you are using on both ends of the connection. There is clearly a mismatch between your sending code and your reading code. And you did not answer my earlier question: "*Did you **validate** that `sizeof(TSampleReq)` is **exactly 276 bytes** in both apps?*".

Comment: I have added extra information in my question and from the server receiving part should be handled for different records and also I have tried your method but still I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: you are NOT using the technique I described, not even close. Your use of `ExtractToBytes()` is all wrong, and is the root of your issue. I have posted an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `ExtractToBytes()` is completely wrong.  That method returns whatever *arbitrary* bytes are stored in the `InputBuffer` at that particular moment, which may be less than, or more than, what you are actually expecting.

If your client is sending a fixed-sized record each time, you should be reading exactly that many bytes, no more, no less:

```
var
  ReceivedIDBytes: TServerRecord;
begin
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadBytes(ReceivedIDBytes.PointerMessage.tyTIDBytes, SizeOf(TSampleReq));  // <-- HERE!!!
  ReceivedIDBytes.ClientSocket := AContext.Connection;
  MessageProcessorThread.ProcessMessageQueue.Enqueue(ReceivedIDBytes);
end;
```

However, if the size of the record depends on the message code, then your client should send the number of bytes in a record before sending the actual record bytes:

```
var
  tyTIDBytes: TIdBytes;
begin
  tyTIDBytes := RawToBytes(TSampleReq, SizeOf(TSampleReq));
  FIdTCPClient.IOHandler.Write(Int32(Length(tyTIDBytes)));
  FIdTCPClient.IOHandler.Write(tyTIDBytes);
end;
```

And then the server can read the byte count before reading the bytes:

```
var
  ReceivedIDBytes: TServerRecord;
begin
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadBytes(ReceivedIDBytes.PointerMessage.tyTIDBytes, AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadInt32);  // <-- HERE!!!
  ReceivedIDBytes.ClientSocket := AContext.Connection;
  MessageProcessorThread.ProcessMessageQueue.Enqueue(ReceivedIDBytes);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks. It works fine when the client application runs in the desktop and there is not packet missing. But when I tried to run in Android mobile, _value6_ does not received. And is there any limitation is there for android firemonkey mobile app?

Comment: @Work2Enjoy-Enjoy2Work the code I have shown works equally on all platforms. If it is not working for you, there must still a mismatch in your code somewhere. You need to debug your code. You STILL have not answered my earlier question. This is the last time I'm going to ask: "*Is `sizeof(TSampleReq)` **exactly 276 bytes** in all of your apps?*" Did you validate that `TIdIOHandler.ReadInt32()` is returning the expected value every time? If not, make sure you are using an up-to-date version of Indy. IIRC, there was an endian bug on Android that I fixed awhile back ago.

Comment: Thanks @Remy. Now I'm receiving the proper data in Server side. And is there any size limitation for the particular packets which is need to be send?

Comment: @Work2Enjoy-Enjoy2Work it is limited to 2GB, the max value of `Int32`.